Adding a new project to a solution and git
I created a new project within an existing solution in VS 2022 a few weeks ago just to discover now that it's not being added to the azure dev ops git with the other projects in this solution.
When looking at the items in the new project, the "lock" is missing.  Typically, in the past, I was able to right click and add to solution control or something like that.
However, that menu option is missing.  In team foundation, it was always simple.  Now, it seems that I'm always fighting something with git...
I've gone through several items here that refer to options under the file menu which don't exist or doing the right click on the project in the solution explorer and adding to the source control which doesn't exist.
I was expecting this to be automatic since the solution is added to source control...
Anyone know how can I resolve this and add this existing project to the git solution which already exists? (Azure)

I'm not exactly sure what your specific issue is, but with Git in AzDO, I think you can simply create the new Git repo in AzDO first, and then you either clone it and start working, or if you have an existing local repo, you setup your remote to point to that new repo in AzDO and then push. (And possibly force push the default branch if it already has a commit for the README file.)

Note my previous comment assumes you are wishing to create a new repository. If you are simply adding a solution to an existing repo, then clone that repo locally if you don't have it already, create a new branch to work on, then copy your solution folder structure into that repo, then stage, commit, and push. When you're done with your code, perhaps create a Pull Request to merge that code into a shared branch.

Side note, in order to use Git, either in a command line or in a UI tool such as Visual Studio, you must be working inside of a Git repo. You can tell that you're inside of a Git repo by the existence of a .git folder at the root of the repo.

I think it was because I had VS create the original project under its own folder, then when I went to create the next project it put it at the same level as the original project.

I ended up removing the project from the solution.
Creating a new repository for the new app (which is related but it doesn't matter that its own repository.
Rename the project folder in the solution
Open a new VS, download the new (and blank) repository to the original folder name under the solution (the original renamed project)
Copy the files from within the copied folder into the newly created repository
Open the solution, add the files and send them up to Azure Dev Ops.
Close VS
Open a new VS with the original solution
Add the newly created project to the existing solution.
Now, it will add the files / updates to the git in their own repositories.
It's unfortunate that I couldn't add it to the original project, but it's not the end of the world for me.  At least the files are up there now.
